# JAVA Servlet Tict Tac Toe w/Buttons

Tags: java, html

We were supposed to design a tic tac toe servlet, using buttons that will turn into x's or o's. This works using `href`, but not `submit`:

`out.print("<input type=submit name=row + column >Play</a>");`

`out.print("<a href=\"TicTacToe?row=" +  row + "&column=" + column + "\">Play</a>");`

The `href` version when ran will display an 3x3 array of hyperlinks that will switch to x's and o's depending on player turn.

The `button` version does nothing... I've searched all over but am unsure how to make it work.

***EDIT***  Here's the rest of the code I tried the changes Andreas mentioned no luck, but I did see how to do a few new things   Scroll down until you see the asterisks across the page

```
package TicTacToe;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(
    description = "Game request and response handler",
    urlPatterns = {
      "/TicTacToe"
    })

public class TicTacToe extends HttpServlet {

  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private char[][] board; // 3 x 3 array
  private final static char[] markers = {'O', 'X'};
  private int currentPlayer; // 0 or 1
  private int moveCount; // set to 9 when the game is over
  private final Random random = new Random();

  public TicTacToe() {
    super();
    reset();
  }

  private void generateCell(int row, int column, PrintWriter out) {
    out.print("<td>");
    if (board[row][column] == 0) {
      if (moveCount < 9) {

 ****************************************************************************

          out.print("<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"document.location='TicTacToe?row=" + row + "&column=" + column + "\">Play</button>");


****************************************************************************

      } else {
        // empty cell do nothing
      }
    } else {
      out.print(board[row][column]);
    }
    out.print("</td>");
  }

  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (request.getParameter("reset") != null) {
      reset();
    } else if (request.getParameter("computer") != null) {
      computeMove();
    } else if (request.getParameter("row") != null) {
      int row = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("row"));
      int column = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("column"));
      if (board[row][column] == 0) {
        board[row][column] = markers[currentPlayer];
        currentPlayer = (currentPlayer + 1) % 2;
        moveCount += 1;
      }
    }
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String docType
        = "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 "
        + "transitional//en\">\n";
    out.println(docType
        + "<html>\n"
        + "<head><title>Tic Tac Toe</title></head>\n"
        + "<h1 align=\"center\">Tic Tac Toe</h1>\n"
        + "<table align=\"center\">\n");
    String message = markers[currentPlayer] + " turn";
    Character winner = checkWinner();
    if (winner != null) {
      message = winner + " wins";
      moveCount = 9;
    } else if (moveCount == 9) {
      message = "No moves";
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row) {
      out.print("   <tr>\n");
      for (int column = 0; column < 3; ++column) {
        generateCell(row, column, out);
      }
      out.println("</tr>");
    }
    out.println("</table>");
    out.println(
        "<h5 align=\"center\">" + message + "</h5>");
    if (moveCount != 9) {
      out.println("<h5 align=\"center\"><a href=\"TicTacToe?computer=1\">Computed move</a></h5>");
    }
    out.println("<a href=\"TicTacToe?reset=1\">Reset</a>"
        + "</body>\n"
        + "</html>");
  }

  private void reset() {
    board = new char[3][3];
    currentPlayer = 0;
    moveCount = 0;
  }

  // return Character as opposed to char because it returns null when there is no winner
  private Character checkWinner() {
    // check rows
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row) {
      if (board[row][0] != 0 && board[row][0] == board[row][1] && board[row][2] == board[row][1]) {
        return board[row][0];
      }
    }
    // check columns
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; ++column) {
      if (board[0][column] != 0 && board[0][column] == board[1][column] && board[2][column] == board[1][column]) {
        return board[0][column];
      }
    }
    // check diagonals
    if (board[1][1] != 0 && board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[2][2] == board[1][1]) {
      return board[1][1];
    }
    if (board[1][1] != 0 && board[2][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][2] == board[1][1]) {
      return board[1][1];
    }
    return null;
  }

  // play markerToPlay if markerToCheck can win
  private boolean moveToWin(char markerToCheck, char markerToPlay) {
      for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 3; ++column) {
          if (board[row][column] == 0) {
            board[row][column] = markerToCheck;
            if (checkWinner() != null) {
              board[row][column]=markerToPlay;
              return true;
            } else {
              board[row][column] = 0;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
  }

  // naive strategy: occupy the center or a corner in the first move
  // then find a winning move
  // if it does exist block a winning move from opponent
  // if there is no move from the previous line, just pick a move at random
  private void computeMove() {
    if (moveCount >= 9) { // should not happen, but checking anyway
      return;
    }
    if (moveCount == 0) { // occupy center cell
      board[1][1] = markers[currentPlayer];
    } else if (moveCount == 1) {
      if (board[1][1] == 0) {
        board[1][1] = markers[currentPlayer];
      } else { // occupy corner
        board[0][0] = markers[currentPlayer];
      }
    } else {
       // first check if there is a winning play
      boolean played = moveToWin(markers[currentPlayer], markers[currentPlayer]);
      // then move to block the one to win
      if (!played) {
        played =  moveToWin(markers[(currentPlayer + 1) % 2], markers[currentPlayer]);
      }
      // if we did not get a move from above, we just pick a cell at random
      while (!played) {
        int row = random.nextInt(3);
        int column = random.nextInt(3);
        if (board[row][column] == 0) {
          played = true;
          board[row][column] = markers[currentPlayer];
        }
      }
    }
    currentPlayer = (currentPlayer + 1) % 2;
    moveCount += 1;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
          }

          @Override
           protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException {
             processRequest(request, response);
           }

        }
```

Comment: Display <a ...> as button via CSS (possible, but can't say from memory how, im not designer)

Comment: Typical lifecycle of real "button" is FORM with action POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "submit" button only does something if it is inside a `<form>`, in which case it posts the form fields to the form *action*.

A standalone (non-form) button will work if you build the button like this:

```java
// Using <input>
out.print("<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"document.location='TicTacToe?row=" + row + "&column=" + column + "\" value=\"Play\">");

// Using <button>
out.print("<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"document.location='TicTacToe?row=" + row + "&column=" + column + "\">Play</button>");
```

You can even use a `<form>` and `<input type="hidden">` for `row` and `column`, but using `onclick` is easier.